# Map the result of stored procedure with the returning object using .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am new to .net core. I have started with a Get API call that will return a single Employee record as a result from SP based on the Employee Id. I have 2 classes, one is Employee and the other is Address. I have a composition relation between these 2 tables. I want to return the Employee object that contains Employee details along with the list of Addresses. So, my Employee class looks like this:

```
public class Employee{
public string Name {get;set;}
....
public List<Address> Addr {get; set;}
}
```

I am able to return the Employee object containing the Employee details. But, the Addr is returning null.

Here is my code:

```
 public async Task<Employee> GetEmployeeDetails(int employeeid)
    {
            Employee emp;
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {"@employeeid", employeeid }
                    };

            var parameters = new DynamicParameters(dictionary);

            using (IDbConnection con = await GetConnectionAsync(ConfigHandler.GetConnectionString(Constants.DefaultConnectionString)))
            {
                emp = (Employee)await ExecuteQueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<Employee>(con, "GetEmployeeDetails", parameters);
                con.Close();
            }
            return emp;
    }
```

Should I use multiple result sets or a single result set from SP? i.e. the resultset for employees and address differently or Should I return only one result set. Since I am interested in the first address. And secondly, how is it possible to map the result from the Sp to the object.
I will be grateful for any help/advice.
Thanks!

Comment: Hello, can you show the columns that are returned from your sql query?
My first advice would be that you need to know that a row in your SQL result should represent one C# object, SQL does not have a tree/node understanding. So a row is a plain object. The list of addresses is a node. To fill it you can create a class `GetEmployeeDetails` that will represent the exact result from your SQL query and then you do a mapping to your `Employee` class

Comment: Hi @Max, The query I am using in SP is: Select e.name, e.email, e.gender, a.addr, a.city, a.zip from Employee e left join address a on e.employeeid = a.employeeid
where e.employeeId = @_ employeeId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a class that should look like this

```
    public class GetEmployeeDetailsResult 
    {
      public string Name {get;set;}
      public string Email {get;set;}
      public string Gender {get;set;}
      public string Addr {get;set;}
      public string City {get;set;}
      public string Zip {get;set;}
    }
```

In this class you can have a method to map to `Employee` class

```
public Employee MapEmployeeFromGetEmployeeDetailsResult(List<GetEmployeeDetailsResult> source)
{
  var firstElement = source.FirstOrDefault();
   return new Employee
            {
                Name = firstElement.Name,
                Email = firstElement.Email,
                Gender = firstElement.Gender,
                //this line will iterate and create the node for addresses
                Addr = source                  
                    .Select(emp => new Address
                    {
                        Addr = emp.Addr, 
                        City = emp.City,
                        Zip = emp.Zip
                    })
                    .ToList()
            };
}
```

Then use this class as the return type for your SQL query

```
         public async Task<Employee> GetEmployeeDetails(int employeeid)
            {
                    Employee emp;
                    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
                            {
                                {"@employeeid", employeeid }
                            };
        
                    var parameters = new DynamicParameters(dictionary);
        
                    using (IDbConnection con = await GetConnectionAsync(ConfigHandler.GetConnectionString(Constants.DefaultConnectionString)))
                    {
                        var result = await ExecuteQueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<GetEmployeeDetailsResult>(con, "GetEmployeeDetails", parameters);
                        con.Close();
                        emp = new GetEmployeeDetailsResult()
                              .MapEmployeeFromGetEmployeeDetailsResult(result);
                    }
                    return emp;    
    }
```

If you do not want the line `new GetEmployeeDetailsResult() .MapEmployeeFromGetEmployeeDetailsResult(result);` you can put the method `MapEmployeeFromGetEmployeeDetailsResult` to `static` and changed the

```
new GetEmployeeDetailsResult().MapEmployeeFromGetEmployeeDetailsResult(result);
```

to

```
GetEmployeeDetailsResult.MapEmployeeFromGetEmployeeDetailsResult(result);
```